# Annotating bokeh chart plot

Tags: python, plot, bokeh, glyph

Is it possible to annotate or add markers of any form to Bokeh charts (specifically Bar graphs)? Say I want to add an * (asterisks) on top of a bar; is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's always possible to use `.add_glyph` directly, but it is a bit of a pain. The feature to add all the "glyph methods" e.g. `.circle`, `.rect`, etc. is in GitHub `master`, and will be available in the upcoming `0.12` release.

Comment: Thanks for this Bryan. Came across this after looking up .add_glyph (maybe can be of help to someone): [link](https://groups.google.com/a/continuum.io/forum/m/#!topic/bokeh/TRZCirDpl-8)

Comment: Just realized that when I add a glyph using .add_glyph, when I use the components function it breaks giving the error: `TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable`. Without adding the glyph my code works perfectly fine.

Comment: Would need a complete runnable code example to investigate further.

Comment: `from bokeh.models.glyphs import Circle
    from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource
    from bokeh.sampledata.autompg import autompg as df

    plotFig = Bar(df, 'cyl', values='mpg')

    source=ColumnDataSource(
        data=dict(x=5, y=1000)
    )
    circle = Circle(x="x", y="y")
    plotFig.add_glyph(source, circle)
    plotFig.logo = None
    plot_script, plot_div = components(plotFig, INLINE)

    return render_template(
            'plot-bias.html',
            plot_script = plot_script,
            plot_div = plot_div)`

Comment: That's not complete, it's missing imports (e.g. `Bar`, `components`, and `INLINE`) and it's not runnable as-is without whatever `plot-bias.html` is. It's also not formatted in a reasonable way that helps anyone help you. You are asking people to freely donate their time and effort for free. If you want help, you have to go out of your way to ***lower the burden as much as possible, on anyone that might want to help***

Comment: That said, the problem is that you have to pass lists/sequences/arrays as the data to your column data source, e.g. `source=ColumnDataSource( data=dict(x=[5], y=[1000]))` It took me 10 seconds to figure that out once I got it running, but it took me 5 minutes to get running. Please try to always provide more information, because people will not always have the time to try and "fill in the missing gaps"

Comment: Thanks for this and apologies for the poor quality reply. May I add (possibly the obvious) that if the source is different than the bar graph source, the coordinates for the x-axis should be incremental starting with 1 being the first bar etc i.e. if the labels start from [3,4,5] in the bar source, the x-coordinates would still be 1,2,3.

Comment: It's certainly a possibility to consider, I'd suggest making a GH issue to discuss this feature idea (tho also check first, there may already be a similar one)